# ChoiceField: Select a valid choice. That is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as BaseUser

CHOICE_GENDER = (('1', 'Male'), ('2', 'Female'))


class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ', '.join([self.city, self.state])


class Users(BaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(BaseUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICE_GENDER)
    birth = models.DateField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user',)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from .models import Users, Location, CHOICE_GENDER


class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=75)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('city', 'country',)


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=75)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICE_GENDER)
    birth = forms.DateField()
    location = LocationForm()

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birth',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']
        user.birth = self.cleaned_data['birth']
        loc = LocationForm(city=self.cleaned_data['city'], country=self.cleaned_data['country'])
        user.location = loc
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I can't manage to get past the error described in the title. I've tried everything from the suggestions in other questions about the same subject but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have set datatype as **Integer**

```
gender = models.**IntegerField**(choices=CHOICE_GENDER)
```

and your **choices** are given in **String**

```
CHOICE_GENDER = (('1', 'Male'), ('2', 'Female'))
```

Instead of '1' it should be 1

```
CHOICE_GENDER = ((1, 'Male'), (2, 'Female'))
```